# Accurev .acignore

Tags: accurev

I have a directory tree under accurev. In this tree I have a directory work which I want to exclude from versioning for good (including subdirectories). Can I use .acignore?

Answer (score 9):

Yep, you'll need two entries in .acignore for that: one to exclude the directory and the other to exclude its contents (including sub-directories), e.g

```
myproject/bin/Debug
myproject/bin/Debug/*
```

Just keep/promote the .acignore file in the parent of the "myproject" subdirectory.

Comment: I tried it but it wont work. I still see those directories and files in "accurev stat -x".

Comment: Is your equivalent of the "myproject" directory or any of its children currently under source control? If so AccuRev may be disregarding your ignore entries.

Comment: of course it is. I have .acignore file in the root of the project and "work" directory just under root.

Comment: I suggest you update your question with more specifics about what directories are currently under source control, what entries are in your .acignore file currently and where that file is stored. Otherwise it will be difficult to assist.

Answer (score 2):

that is precisely what that file is for.

just add an entry like this to exclude the "work" directory:

```
path/to/directory/work
```

or, if you want to exclude all files and folders named "work" do this:

```
**/work
```

i just tested this to ensure it will work. under accurev version 5.7, you do not require a separate entry to exclude the contents of "work". however, i wouldn't recommend using the "**" wildcard for such a generic file name "work".

if you want to share your .acignore file with other users of your project be sure to promote the .acignore file itself so that others can pull it down.

this is the .acignore file that i put in the root of any accurev repository on my machine to exclude standard maven, intellij, eclipse, and git files:

```
**/target
**/.idea
**/.metadata
**/.classpath
**/.project
**/.settings
**/.git
**/*.iml
**/*.ipr
**/.gitignore
**/atlassian-ide-plugin.xml
```

that said, i did once have a colleague break our continuous integration build by creating a package named "target", so use that one with caution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, acignore files can be used to tell accurev to exclude/ignore files from the directory. But the scope of .acignore file is restricted to the current directory. So you will need to create .acignore files on per-directory basis.

Ref. http://www.accurev.com/download/docs/5.4.0_books/AccuRev_WebHelp/AccuRev_TechNotes/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm#href=per_dir_pathname_opt.html&single=true